# iOS faster saving of photos to album

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, avfoundation, alassetslibrary

I'm using the ALAssets library to write photos I take to the album using the library's
    writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:

However, when I take photos to often the images take too much RAM so my app crashes.

So.. what I did is I disabled the "take photo" button at the beginning of its IBAction and unblocked it in the completionBlock.

And.. that makes it really slow. So my question is.. does anyone know a faster way of saving photos, or at least an easy way to keep a manageable number of them in RAM so that the first few can be made faster.. The thing is I haven't found an easy way to check if I'll have enough memory if I take a new photo.. Thanks!